# Should the OP really approve/reject a suggested edit in one review?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

So there was [this](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/432407) edit I made, and it got rejected by the OP even though we **NEED** formatting! So should the OP really be able to reject like that? Maybe needs 2 people?

Comment: And I don't see how its destructive. But enjoy your edit Oli!

Comment: That edit confused me too. I did not get that all info was just formatted. I reviewed it and skipped )))). I reviewed hundreds of edits and this was confusing for me. OP is a new user :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The difference between our edits is mine didn't have to go through the review queue so the OP couldn't reject it. Yours would have likely passed if it weren't for the OP. It was a good edit.

That said, unless it's deleted or locked, **the OP can always immediately push an edit**. That might be improving a suggestion, or rolling one back. Ultimately it's their question and the system automatically assumes they understand what's best for their question. If they want to go to war over an edit, flag it up and we'll put them straight.

Remember that you're dealing with a new user too. The system has confusing bits to it and a new user might see an edit suggestion full of markdown (it looks pretty scary) and try to keep things as static as possible.

I'm sorry your edit didn't go through. That's just the way it is with newer users some times.

Comment: Well if they rollback they we just keep going back to the formatted version?

Comment: @UniKitty No, flag it as Oli said in his answer, I guess he has plans to take care of that